# How to prevent Dependency objects to be instantiated somewhere else?

Tags: c#, mvvm, dependency-injection

So basicly if i have a service `MyMonkeyService` which implements interface `IMyMonkeyService` and i make a register a DI object like :

```
SimpleIOC.Default.Register(Of IMyMonkeyService, MyMonkeyService)
```

How do i make sure that some developer after me not going to create new instance of MyMonkeyService somewhere in the application? I cant make Service's constructor private or protected, because then DI wouldnt work, if i create a Init() method on the service, it will still be available to the "new developer".

Comment: Is this question concerning `SimpleIOC` in specific? Or is this a more general question?

Comment: No easy/technical way to make it impossible. Educate them, sanction them. Have violators take care of the continues integration/build system until next one makes a mistake. Code Reviews help to detect violations. If nothing helps, fire them and get competent developers ;)

Comment: You can't.  Now, the real question is, *why* you think you need to do this, and what other ways of reaching your goals exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about making `MyMonkeyService` a [singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)?

You would have an implementation like this:

```
public class MyMonkeyService : IMyMonkeyService
{
    private static MyMonkeyService _instance;

    public static IMyMonkeyService Instance
    {
        get
        {
            // Gets the singleton if created, otherwise create a new instance
            return _instance != null ? _instance : (_instance = new MyMonkeyService());
        }
    }

    // Private constructor
    private MyMonkeyService()
    {
       // ...
    }
}
```

I don't know what DI framework you are using, but you would end up with something like the following:

```
SimpleIOC.Default.Register(Of IMyMonkeyService, MyMonkeyService.Instance);
```

Everytime your service is injected, the **same instance** will be used.

Comment: This will defenetly work if constructor of the service doesnt have any parameters, but if it does, it wouldnt work unless instance will be transformed into method instead of property

Comment: Singletons are an anti-pattern and shouldn't be used with MVVM pattern, n-layer architecture or any serious software development. Also you break the IoC pattern as you can't resolve dependencies through your IoC container by using this pattern. It all leads to bad to main and tightly coupled code

Answer (score 1):

If you require multiple instances, you cant. Everything you make available to the DI container will be available for another developer.

You can write an [**analyzer**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn879356.aspx) though, which checks for instantiation of `MyMonkeyService` and emits an appropriate error.

[This](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cdndevs/archive/2015/11/17/building-a-code-analyzer-for-the-roslyn-analyzer-project.aspx?utm_campaign=C%23%2BWeekly&utm_medium=email&utm_source=C%23_Weekly_37) or [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/861548/Roslyn-Code-Analysis-in-Easy-Samples-Part) may help you getting started.

Roselyn Analyzers let you write code analysis tools that check the code for specific patterns and can emit errors and warnings accordingly. You can even define fixes for that pattern.

Comment: I think you suggestions might be to "big". It should be enough to use the singleton pattern or use some static properties to flag the instance as "in use".

Comment: @Shnugo I agree with you that the singleton pattern should suffice. However, I just wanted to let him know that there is something that can help if it doesnt.

Comment: Just read a bit about Analyzer, it will be a bit too big implementation for now. but thanks for letting me know that it exists!